# SwiftUI : how to make this raising up view

Tags: swiftui

I am just curious for this animation, when i click one button, the origin page will fall down a bit and the new page will raise up with a cross button on top left corner.
Seems it's quite a common behavior, anyone who know is there any official api for this animation ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just two sheets presented, one on top of the other.

Example code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isPresented = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Content")

            Button("Present sheet") {
                isPresented = true
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
                MainSheet()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct MainSheet: View {
    @State private var isPresented = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Sheet content")

            Button("Present another sheet") {
                isPresented = true
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
                Text("Final content")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]